# Symfony Validators not loading?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following composer file:

```
{
  "require": {
    "doctrine/orm": "2.4.*",
    "doctrine/migrations": "1.0.*@dev",
    "symfony/validator": "2.8.*@dev",
    "slim/slim": "~2.6",
    "freya/freya-exception": "0.0.7",
    "freya/freya-loader": "0.2.2",
    "freya/freya-templates": "0.1.2",
    "freya/freya-factory": "0.0.8"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"": ""}
  }
}
```

And I created the following Entity, or as I call them model:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $firstName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $lastName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, unique=true, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $userName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, unique=true, nullable=false)
     * @Assert\Email
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=500, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $password;

    ...
}
```

Now when I run `"vendor/bin/doctrine" migrations:diff` I get an error:

```
  [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Email" in property App\Models\User::$email does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded.
```

The documentation for symfony doesn't state anything about how to set this up properly, aside from their [github page](https://github.com/symfony/Validator) and their actual documentation states, pretty much the same.

So why am I getting this error? I looked and the class DOES exist under the list of validators installed ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need a little glue to get it to work with your microframework's bootstrapping:

`\Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry::registerLoader(array($loader, 'loadClass'));`

[Link to information](https://github.com/dflydev/dflydev-doctrine-orm-service-provider/issues/45) that may be of use.

Comment: This still leaves me with the same problem.

Comment: You need to `require` it: `$loader = require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';` Make sure your path is correct.

Comment: Sorry I ended up deleting my response, but now that it seems to be working - or at least this call works, the out put is still the same, do I need to put this code some where specific? Like the bootstrap.php that I have or in the Entity?